# Julia - Repeat entries of a vector by another vector (inner)

Tags: julia

I have an array `x` and I would like to repeat each entry of `x` a number of times specified by the corresponding entries of another array `y`, of the same length of `x`.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    # Array to be repeated
y = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3]    # Repetitions for each element of x
# result should be [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
```

Is there a way to do this in Julia?

Comment: Oh apparently one can do `vcat(fill.(x, y)...)` although I don't quite understand how it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` vectors constitute what is called a [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) of the vector `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]`. So if you take the inverse of the run-length encoding, you will get the vector you are looking for. The [StatsBase.jl](https://juliastats.org/StatsBase.jl/stable/) package contains the `rle` and `inverse_rle` functions. We can use `inverse_rle` like this:

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

julia> y = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3];

julia> inverse_rle(x, y)
11-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
 5
 5
 5
```

Comment: This is definitely the best option here. Fast (slightly beats even my "manual way" answer), easy to understand and maintain - well worth the cost of one (pretty standard) package dependency.

Comment: @sundar-RememberMonica Just eyeballing the source code it looks pretty close to your "manual way", the nested loop is written a bit different but as far as I can tell it does the same iterations.

Comment: @BatWannaBe Yeah, and it's instructive to see the differences that make up for those last bits of performance difference. Avoiding the `enumerate` by not throwing away the `length` result at the top seems to be the big one, but the little ones like hoisting the array-indexing out of the inner loop also seem to add up.

Answer (score 4):

You've given what I would have suggested as the answer already in your comment:

```
vcat(fill.(x, y)...)
```

How does this work? Start with `fill`:

```
help?> fill

  fill(x, dims::Tuple)
  fill(x, dims...)

  Create an array filled with the value x. For example, fill(1.0, (5,5)) returns a 5×5 array of floats, with each element initialized to 1.0.
```

This is a bit more complicated than it needs to be for our case (where we only have one dimension to fill into), so let's look at a simple example:

```
julia> fill(1, 3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
```

so `fill(1, 3)` just means "take the number one, and put this number into a one-dimensional array 3 times."

This of course is exactly what we want to do here: for every element in `x`, we want an array that holds this element multiple times, with the multiple given by the corresponding element in `y`. We could therefore loop over `x` and `y` and do something like:

```
julia> for (xᵢ, yᵢ) ∈ zip(x, y)
           fill(xᵢ, yᵢ)
       end
```

Now this loop doesn't return anything, so we'd have to preallocate some storage and assign to that within the loop. A more concise way of writing this while automatically returning an object would be a comprehension:

```
julia> [fill(xᵢ, yᵢ) for (xᵢ, yᵢ) ∈ zip(x, y)]
5-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2]
 [3]
 [4, 4]
 [5, 5, 5]
```

and even more concisely, we can just use broadcasting:

```
julia> fill.(x, y)
5-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [1, 1, 1]
 [2, 2]
 [3]
 [4, 4]
 [5, 5, 5]
```

so from the comprehension or the broadcast we are getting a vector of vectors, each vector being an element of `x` repeated `y` times. Now all that remains is to put these together into a single vector by concatenating them vertically:

```
julia> vcat(fill.(x, y)...)
11-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
 5
 5
 5
```

Here we are using [splatting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/faq/#The-two-uses-of-the-...-operator:-slurping-and-splatting) to essentially do:

```
z = fill.(x, y)
vcat(z[1], z[2], z[3], z[4], z[5])
```

Note that splatting can have suboptimal performance for arrays of variable length, so a better way is to use `reduce` which is special cased for this and will give the same result:

```
reduce(vcat, fill.(x, y))
```

Comment: Could you comment more on why splatting large arrays (or perhaps more generally, iterables) can have bad performance? My only guess would be latency from compiling the method for every length, but I thought Julia didn't automatically specialize on VarArgs for that very reason (mentioned in Performance Tips).

Comment: That's a fair point, my answer was worded somewhat misleadingly there - it's more variable length than the length per se. Of course in a case like this it doesn't really make a difference, it would only matter if `vcat(fill.(x, y)...)` happens in a hot loop with changing `x` and `y` length.

Comment: I looked it up closer in the performance tips and forums and found a couple things. Someone does claim that variable length specialization is a problem, and the performance tips does say a VarArg will make a method specialize if it is not just passed to another method (not sure how, since everything is a method call). Someone also pointed out that variable arguments (even if splatted from a lazy iterable) are packaged into a length-dependent Tuple type, so that's a clear cost of time and memory. In any case, the proper way is a loop or reduce with binary methods, as in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

If performance is a priority, you can also do it the long, manual way:

```
function runlengthdecode(vals::Vector{T}, reps::Vector{<:Integer}) where T
  length(vals) == length(reps) || throw(ArgumentError("Same number of values and counts expected"))

  result = Vector{T}(undef, sum(reps))
  resind = 1
  for (valind, numrep) in enumerate(reps)
    for i in 1:numrep
      @inbounds result[resind] = vals[valind]
      resind += 1
    end
  end

  result
end
```

This runs about 12 times faster than the `vcat`/`fill` based method for the given data, likely because of avoiding creating all the intermediate `fill`ed vectors.

You can also instead use `fill!` on the preallocated result's `@view`s, by replacing the loop in above code with:

```
  for (val, numrep) in zip(vals, reps)
    fill!(@view(result[resind:resind + numrep - 1]), val)
    resind += numrep
  end
```

which has comparable performance.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for completeness, a comprehension can be quite handy for this. And it's faster than `fill` and `vcat`.

```
julia> [x[i] for i=1:length(x) for j=1:y[i]]
11-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
 5
 5
 5
```